My game is so laggy
I'm trying to play Minecraft with PolyMC, but the game is lagging a lot. I'm only getting 5~ FPS. I'm using an AMD R5 220 graphics card and an Intel® Core™ i5-4590. What should I do? Please help.
EDIT: Removed ImmediatelyFast modpack. I don't know why lags but fixed. Thanks All :)

try it on vanilla, if is able see the server properties are u useing to run the server, if the 'view-distance' directive in your server is higher than 5 that will be to much to your server
